# How to display the Composite Collider to a player

Tags: unity, collider

I have a GameObject with a Composite Collider on it.  There are 2 nested GameObjects under it, each with a Sprite:

[image]

I am making an educational game, and for pedagogical reasons I'd like to display the Composite Collider to the player...  is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried to use a line renderer to just draw all the points of your composite collider? https://forum.unity.com/threads/using-linerender-to-draw-edge-of-composite-collider-in-game.692335/

Comment: @Zibelas Thanks for the link, I will try that out!